# Symfony2 File Upload with own Entity

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

I have one entity "Task" and another "Attachments". I want to store all attachments in their own table associated with their task and user. So I created this entity Class:

```
<?php

namespace Seotool\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="attachments")
 */
class Attachments {

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
public $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
public $path;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="attachments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $User;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="attachments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="editor", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $Editor;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Task", inversedBy="attachments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="task", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $Task;

/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
 */
private $file;

/**
 * Sets file.
 *
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 */
public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
}

/**
 * Get file.
 *
 * @return UploadedFile
 */
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->path
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->path
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded
    // documents should be saved
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

protected function getUploadDir()
{
    // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
    // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
    return 'uploads/documents';
}

....
```

In my Form Type for my Task Form I want to add now the file upload. But how can I do this?
I can't add `$builder->add('Attachment', 'file');` because it's not the same entity. So how can I do it, so that I have in my FormType of Entity Task the upload field which stores the uploaded data in the table of Entity Class Attachment??

**EDIT**

this is my Controller:

```
/**
@Route(
 *     path = "/taskmanager/user/{user_id}",
 *     name = "taskmanager"
 * )
 * @Template()
 */
public function taskManagerAction($user_id, Request $request)
{

     /* #### NEW TASK #### */

    $task = new Task();
    $attachment = new Attachments();

    $task->getAttachments()->add($attachment);
    $addTaskForm = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);

    $addTaskForm->handleRequest($request);

    if($addTaskForm->isValid()):

        /* User Object of current Users task list */
        $userid = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:User')
            ->find($user_id);

        $task->setDone(FALSE);
        $task->setUser($userid);
        $task->setDateCreated(new \DateTime());
        $task->setDateDone(NULL);
        $task->setTaskDeleted(FALSE);

        $attachment->setTask($task);
        $attachment->setUser($userid);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($task);
        $em->persist($attachment);
        $em->flush();

        $this->log($user_id, $task->getId(), 'addTask');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('taskmanager', array('user_id' => $user_id)));

    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename your entity from `Attachments` to `Attachment` as it would be storing data of only one attachment.

In your case you need Symfony2 form collection type to allow adding attachment in task form (TaskType):

```
$builder->add('attachments', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new AttachmentType(),
    // 'allow_add' => true,
    // 'allow_delete' => true,
    // 'delete_empty' => true,
));
```

You will also need to create AttachmentType form type for single attachment entity.

Doc of collection field type: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html
More information about embedding form collection you can find on: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Then also read sections:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-tags-to-be-removed

Comment: Please let me know if you run into any problems.

Comment: I made a new answer, would be happy, when you could take a look :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that's because you have to initialize new instance of TaskType in your controller - there are no attachments at the beginning that are assigned to this task.

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $task = new Task();

    $attachment1 = new Attachment();
    $task->getAttachments()->add($attachment1);
    $attachment2 = new Attachment();
    $task->getAttachments()->add($attachment2);
    // create form
    $form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    ...
}
```

Now there should be 2 file input for new attachments.

Comment: I get this exception: FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function add() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Seotool/src/Seotool/MainBundle/Controller/DashboardController.php line 52. Line 52 is:         $task->getAttachments()->add($attachment);

Comment: Did you set: $this->attachments = new ArrayCollection(); in constructor of your Task entity class?

Comment: I did it now. The exception is gone but nothing is outputted...No file upload. :-/

Comment: It's explained here:http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html  - try to check your code or give me more code :)

Comment: Thank you! Where can I tell , that Symfony only should add an attachment entry when there is selected a file to upload? Because when I dont select any file , an entry is tried to make but it doesnt work because the fields cannot be NULL. But normally it shouldn't make any entry when there is no file selected

Comment: Try: delete_empty option in your form.

Comment: Still the same exception. I updated my question with the code snippet of my controller, where I set the values for attachments. Maybe there is a mistake? Maybe I need to make IF Question, if attachments is empty?

Comment: By exception you mean: "Symfony only should add an attachment entry when there is selected a file to upload?" I yes you should not to that manually: $attachment->setTask($task); $attachment->setUser($userid);  because this will always save you one attachment.

Comment: Ok, so, but how can I set these both fields anywhere else? Do I have to do it in my Entity Class? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: $attachment->setTask($task); is set by $task->getAttachments()->add($attachment); and $attachment->setUser($userid); should be set just after $attachment = new Attachments();

Answer (score 0):

I added a new Form Type: AttachmentsType.php

```
<?php
namespace Seotool\MainBundle\Form\Type;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class AttachmentsType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name', 'text');
    $builder->add('file', 'file');
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver
            ->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\Attachments'
            ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'attachments';
}
}
```

And used this for embbing it into my form builder of the TaskType.php

```
$builder->add('attachments', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new AttachmentsType(),
));
```

But my output only gives me following HTML:

```
 <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label required">Attachments</label><div id="task_attachments"></div></div><input id="task__token" name="task[_token]" class="form-control" value="brHk4Kk4xyuAhST3TrTHaqwlnA03pbJ5RE4NA0cmY-8" type="hidden"></form>
```